# How to add environment variable in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables

Is there any way I can add environment variable in Windows via C++?

They have to be added in "My computer->properties->advanced->environment variables"

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically adding a directory to Windows PATH environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919125/programmatically-adding-a-directory-to-windows-path-environment-variable)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set local environment variables in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899517/set-local-environment-variables-in-c)

Comment: @Aamir: OP said "in Windows". Your link requires it only for the running process. Also see the reply from Felice Pollano which makes the same (IMO wrong) assumption.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) :

> To programmatically add or modify
>   system environment variables, add them
>   to the
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` registry key, then
>   broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message
>   with `lParam` set to the string
>   "Environment". This allows
>   applications, such as the shell, to
>   pick up your updates ...

Comment: Is there any other way without using registry?

Comment: @code9215: nope, not as of yet, but if you find one, you should write up an answer.

Comment: System is global settings. How about adding on user settings?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know is via the registry.

Hint, the global variables are in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and those for each user in `HKEY_USERS\*\Environment`, where `*` denotes the SID of the user.

Good luck.

Comment: After independent research myself that led me here, I found this to be the easiest mechanism. Just remember that every process that existed *before* you updated the path environment variable may or may not respond as it should to the message you are supposed to send after updating it. Meaning, the change may only apply to new processes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple implementation (Based on the MSDN instruction posted by SteelBytes):

```
bool SetPermanentEnvironmentVariable(LPCTSTR value, LPCTSTR data)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR keyPath = TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment");
    LSTATUS lOpenStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyPath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
    if (lOpenStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        LSTATUS lSetStatus = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)data, strlen(data) + 1);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        if (lSetStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment", SMTO_BLOCK, 100, NULL);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Set local environment variables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899517/set-local-environment-variables-in-c)?

Comment: It's worth noting environment variables created with putenv (or _putenv in Windows) do not persist after the program that created them exits (as the word local indicates). +1 because this solves the problem if you only need the environment variable to be around for the program lifetime

Answer (score -1):

The environment variables in Windows are stored in Windows Registry. You can use "System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable" .NET function for the purpose, please see the documentation of the function at link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx

Comment: He wants to set the variables globally; this function only applies to the current process.

Comment: I think you haven't read the documentation of the function. The function can set the variable for "Process" or "User" or "Machine". You can do it at machine level by passing targer = EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine

Comment: That's a C# function; he's asking about C++.

Comment: OK if you don't want to agree, What can I say. I won't comment any further. Just one last thing for your information. This method can be called fom C++, C#, VB and F# (see given link for sample code for all languages). I agree that the function is part of Framework and is not part of Win32 but the asked question doesn't require that. The question just says "C++ on Windows". I suppose you didn't read the question carefully. Anyways have fun !! :)

Comment: "C++ on Windows" cannot call .Net methods.  (few people use C++/CLI)

Comment: @SLaks Just stumbled upon this. There is actually a C++ function with the same name, that does the same: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That is a Win32 API and has the same local effect I am describing below. Slaks is right. When a new Windows process is created it gets an entire copy of the environment in it's Process Environment Block (this is why a message should be sent after updating). This method only affects that local process, or *children* of that process, if applicable. It has no permanence.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "tchar.h"


void SetUserVariablePath(){
    HKEY hkey;
    long regOpenResult;
    const char key_name[] = "Environment";
    const char path[]="D:/custom_command";                                               //new_value path need to update 
    regOpenResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,key_name, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
    LPCSTR stuff = "VVS_LOGGING_PATH";                                                   //Variable Name 
    RegSetValueEx(hkey,stuff,0,REG_SZ,(BYTE*) path, strlen(path));
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
}



void GetUserVariablePath(){
    static const char path[] = "VVS_LOGGING_PATH" ;                                      //Variable Name 
    static BYTE buffer1[1000000] ;
    DWORD buffsz1 = sizeof(buffer1) ;
    {
        //HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
        const char key_name[] = "Environment";
        HKEY key ;

        if( RegOpenKeyExA( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_name, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, std::addressof(key) ) == 0 &&
            RegQueryValueExA( key, path, nullptr, nullptr, buffer1, std::addressof(buffsz1) ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "The updated value of the user variable is :  " << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer1) << '\n' ;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   
    SetUserVariablePath();
    GetUserVariablePath();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be nice if you were to explain why your answer is better than those already provided.