# Deleting environment variables doesn't work

Tags: windows, cmd, registry, environment-variables

Why deleting an environment variable with `reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V TestVar` in Windows 7 Professional removes it from the registry, but the variable still exists?

Here are the details: I created the following 3 `.cmd` files:

**Check variable.cmd**

```
echo TestVar = %TestVar%
pause
```

**Set variable.cmd**

```
setx TestVar 123
pause
```

**Delete variable.cmd**

```
reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V TestVar
pause
```

Then I follow these steps (double clicking to make sure that I start a new session every time):

1. Double click on `Check variable.cmd` and I see that `TestVar` does not exist
2. Double click on `Set variable.cmd` and it says `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`
3. Double click on `Check variable.cmd` and it shows the variable value. Good!
4. Double click on `Delete variable.cmd` and it says `The operation completed successfully.`
5. Double click on `Check variable.cmd` and it still shows the variable value. Bad!
6. Click on the Start menu, type `environment`, click on `Edit environment variables for your account` to open the `Environment Variables` dialog box, click `OK` without changing anything
7. Double click on `Check variable.cmd` and the variable does not exist anymore

I can find the value in the registry after step 2, I cannot find it after step 4, but step 5 still finds it. And even if I don't change anything, step 6 really deletes the variable.

Comment: You have to broadcast a message to notify applications (in this case, Windows Explorer) of the change.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5246097/886887

Comment: @HarryJohnston: How do I broadcast the message from a batch file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem. I don't know if it is the correct solution, but it works for me:

**Check variable.cmd**

```
set TestVar
@pause
```

**Set variable.cmd**

```
setx TestVar 123
@pause
```

**Delete variable.cmd**

```
reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V TestVar
setx DummyVarUsedToDelete ""
reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V DummyVarUsedToDelete
@pause
```

`setx` cannot be used to delete a variable, as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx), but it does the missing broadcasting after a variable has been removed from the registry with `reg delete`.

**EDIT**

I added a line to delete the `DummyVarUsedToDelete` from the registry. This will not be broadcasted, but it is a small temporary problem.

Comment: Note that this solution leaves behind an empty entry for `DummyVarUsedToDelete` in the registry, which should probably be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setx` to delete an environment variable, this will broadcast the correct message:

```
setx TestVar ""
reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V TestVar
```

(As discussed in the comments, using `setx` by itself will leave an empty entry behind in the registry, which should be deleted for the sake of consistency.)

Comment: From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx:You cannot use the setx command to remove values that have been added to the local or system environments. You can use set with a variable name and no value to remove a corresponding value from the local environment.

Comment: Works for me.  I suspect that part of the documentation is out of date.

Comment: It changes the variable value from whatever it is to "",  but it does not delete the variable. Often an empty string has the same effect as a non existing variable, but I want to delete it

Comment: It *does* delete the variable - that is, the variable will no longer appear in the environment block for new processes, I've checked this - but it does leave an empty entry behind in the registry, which is probably not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The registry is read at boot. When a program is started it gets a copy of it's parent's environment, usually Explorer.exe's environment.

As the comment says, explorer (or any other graphical program that acts on the message) if it gets a message from some other program (like setx) warning it that the registry has been changed, rereads the registry.

The answer is simple

Use `set` and `setx` on sequential lines.

Comment: The problem is on the delete, not on the set. It looks like the `setx` does its job and Explorer.exe is notified. The problem is that `reg delete` does its job, but does not notify Explorer.exe

Answer (score 0):

DELETING SYSTEM PATH VARIABLE

Method 1:

```
set var = C:\Users\mahidhai\cygwin64\usr\local\bin
REG delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /F /V var
```

In my case , it didn't work even though i ran as administrator .
Command prompt displays error registry key not found

In such case go directly to registry keys file

Method2:

```
Go To register editor .
Run -> regedit
NAvigate to 
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Edit directly the register key, by clicking on the register key name .

This should work fine

Method 3:

```
Sometimes not updated windows could be the issue . Check if any updates  available . If so update immediately
```