# Set system variable from C++

Tags: c++, shell, scripting

This shell script

```
#!/bin/csh
set VAR=12345
echo $VAR
```

will peacefully give the output 12345 at shell. 
I need to use C++ to do the same in some part of the code:

```
string str = "12345";
retValue="set var1= "+str;      
system(retValue1.c_str());
system("echo $var1");
```

This doesn't create a system variable var1 and echos null which is understandable as each system function would create a child process with different environment variables. So I combine them as follows using just one system function...but it echos null again.

```
retValue="set var1= "+str;
retValue1=retValue+";\n echo $var1";
system(retValue1.c_str());
```

Can someone please guide me to set up the system variable thru C++. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think he wants to change an environment variable in the parent shell, which is impossible.... See my reply

Answer (score 15):

Look at [setenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv) in `<cstdlib>`:

```
#include <cstdlib>

setenv("VAR", "12345", true);
```

Comment: +1 for using the correct function.  Several other answers recommend putenv, but putenv *should not be used*.  setenv is a much better interface.  In particular, putenv( var ) where var is an automatic variable will often have unexpected behavior.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you elaborate why not putenv()? Just curious

Comment: The man page says it best: `The string pointed to by string becomes part of the environment.  A program should not alter or free the string, and should not use stack or other transient string variables as arguments to putenv().  The setenv() function is strongly preferred to putenv().`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `putenv()`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
putenv("VAR=12345");
```

This is very convenient, but the string is not copied by `putenv`. This means that if you modify it later, then you modify the environment. That's not an issue for a literal, but the way you are forming your strings, using `std::string` is not readily compatible with `putenv()`.

The alternative then is to use `setenv()`

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
setenv("VAR", "12345", true);
```

With `setenv()`, copies of the input are made and you are safe to dispose of the strings after calling `setenv()`.

Comment: Good, I'm glad to hear it. Please remember to accept one of the answers. Your choice as to which one.

Comment: +1: In particular, if you invoke putenv( v ) where v is an automatic variable and then return from the function, the environment is borked.  Do not use putenv.  Always use setenv.

Answer (score 1):

You basically can't do that.

You could call [putenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putenv) to *change environment variables* in **your own process and in all future children processes**, but there is **no way** (and this is good) **to change the environment of the *parent* shell process**.

You could have a use convention for your C++ program that e.g. it is outputting some shell commands to be sourced (or `eval`-ed) by the user. An example of this is `ssh-agent -s`.

Comment: The original poster's example is a `system("set X=foo")` which don't work as he expects.... I'm surprised of the downvote and of the other answers. There is no way a Linux program can forcibly change the environment of the parent shell (if any).

Comment: In fact poster's comment to my answer seems to confirm my suspicions, but I do think there's a lot of scope for confusion here!!

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is probably `putenv()`. You didn't specify which OS you are on, so I'll assume Linux because that's the man page I have handy:

> int putenv(char *string);
>
> The putenv() function adds or changes the value of environment
>   variables. The argument string is of the form name=value.  If name
>   does not already exist in the environment, then string is added to the
>   environment.  If name does exist, then the value of name in the
>   environment is changed to value.  The string pointed to by string
>   becomes part of the environment, so altering the string changes the
>   environment.

IIRC, there is a putenv on win32 as well. Finally you might try looking at [this question, possibly a dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899517/set-local-environment-variables-in-c)

Comment: setenv should be preferred over putenv.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers explains correctly as to how to set environment variable from a C++ program which is basically `setenv()`

The only other point i wanted to make is that *why* your approach doesn't work? The reason is, that when a process is loaded, the `system` command is loaded with new context - an equivalent of a new shell. Actually your environment variable *is* getting set but when you comeback it is lost.

Refer to this http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/setenv.html.

Infact, the `setenv()` sets the env variables of *parent* process! Which is why it works for you.

Comment: `setenv()` modifies the environment of the calling process

Answer (score 0):

Note that the otherwise excellent [CPPreference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) does not seem to mention `setenv` among the functions available in the `<cstdlib>` header, only `getenv`. This may not be a problem though as I could use `setenv` by `#include`-ing `<cstdlib>` on a Centos 7 system with GCC 9.1. I suspect in most cases `<cstdlib>` is just a thin wrapper around `<stdlib.h>`.

Another small thing to note is that `setenv` takes C-style character arguments (also for the *value* of the environment variable to be set). If you use C++ strings (as you should), don't forget to convert them using their `.c_str()` method.