# Setting environment variables for a specific run of a specific process

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables

Is it possible to set the environment variables of a process "A" in a way that they will be valid only for its current run (process "A" will be started by my process) using C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are prepared to rely on the Windows API, when you call the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) function to launch a process, you have the `lpEnvironment` parameter.

Normally you pass `NULL` which means, *use the environment of the creating process*. However, you can supply an environment block which will be used by the new process.

The environment block that you pass is a null-terminated block of null-terminated strings. For example:

```
"MyVar=MyValue\0MyOtheVar=MyOtherValue\0\0"
```

defines two separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the environment variables does not cause problems for your current process, please look at [Setting Environment Variables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899517/set-local-environment-variables-in-c).

Tip: any programs forked by your process will only have the environment variables and values you provide for them.